# Adding multiple markers with similar LAT/LONG'S

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am currently creating a iPhone app where a map is required to  pinpoint points of interest but the locations are very close together and when i use the code below only one marker appears

```
  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
   mapView_.myLocationEnabled=YES;
      self.view = mapView_;

//markers
//.......




GMSMarker *hotel = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
hotel.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.458788,-81.470522);
hotel.title = @"International Palms Hotel";
hotel.snippet=@"Phone number: 800-354-8332";
hotel.map =mapView_;

GMSMarker *ksc = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
ksc.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.458788,-80.6508);
ksc.title = @"Kennedy Space Center Visitor Complex";
ksc.snippet=@"Day 2 activity";
ksc.map =mapView_;

GMSMarker *bc = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
bc.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.458788,-81.470522);
bc.title = @"Cocoa Beach";
bc.snippet=@"Day 2";
bc.map =mapView_;

GMSMarker *bg = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
bg.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.458788,-81.470522);
bg.title = @"Busch Gardens";
bg.snippet=@"Day 3";
bg.map =mapView_;


GMSMarker *ww = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
ww.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.458788,-81.470523);
ww.title = @"“Wet and Wild” Water Park";
ww.snippet=@"Day 4";
ww.map =mapView_;
```

Any help would be so helpful

thanks

tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your lat/lon coordinates are correct? Your hotel, bc and bg markers have the exact same coordinate, and the ww marker is only off by 0.000001 of a degree of longitude.

Note that 0.000001 of a degree works out to about 11 centimetres or less, so it's unlikely that the points you're displaying are actually that close together?

Answer (score 1):

If you repeatedly tap the marker, you should see the infowindow popup change content as the markers are cycled through.